# Ideals in Principal Ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $A$ is Principal Ring and $\mathcal{F} = \{I_{1},I_{2},\dots\}$ a family of ideals of $A$.

If $ I_{1} \supsetneq I_{2} \supsetneq \dots$ show that $\displaystyle \cap_{i=1}^{\infty} I_{i} = \{0\}. $

How can I do it? For principal ideals is easy to see that is Noetherian (similar question).

Comment: @Gae.S. A PID skims very close to being Artinian, in a sense:  It's known that a ring $R$ is Artinian iff $R/I$ is finitely cogenerated for every ideal $I$. In fact, $R/I$ is finitely cogenerated for every nonzero $I$, and not finitely cogenerated for $I=\{0\}$ in this case.

Answer (score 5):

This is false.

Take $R=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ and $I_i = (\prod_{j=0}^ip_j)\times \mathbb Z$ for an enumeration of the prime numbers $\{ p_i\mid i\in\mathbb N\}$.

The intersection is $\{0\}\times \mathbb Z$.

(Or as egreg points out, $p_j=p$ for a fixed prime $p$ (so that you get prime powers) would also do the trick.)

---

Maybe you meant principal ideal *domain*?

Then the ideals containing $(x)$ correspond to divisors of $x$, and there are only finitely many if $x\neq 0$, since it is also a UFD.

Comment: So, in question just have Principal Ring.. But thank you, this help me so much!

Comment: @LucasdeSouzaLima It *could* be that your author just means "principal ideal domain" when they say "principal ideal ring"

Comment: You're missing a $\mathbb{Z}$ in the description of $I_i$. Wouldn't $I_n=p^n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ be simpler?

Comment: @egreg I see $\mathbb Z$ in my descsription of $I_i$ in my browser...  Yeah, powers of a single prime would be simpler wouldn't it. At the time I wrote it I just wanted to make it obvious it had too many prime divisors, and that's what occurred to me.

Comment: @egreg. `I_i = (\prod_{j=0}^ip_j)\times \mathbb Z`

Comment: `I_i=(\prod_{j=0}^i p_j)\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}`

Comment: @egreg You don’t like the notation $(x)$ as the principal ideal generated by $x$?

Comment: @rschwieb As the formula is written, I didn’t even think to it! 